# Swift Flat Map Dictionary Data Structure

Tags: swift

I'm trying to map a dictionary to a flattened array of its values. Turn this object into `[Object]`

```
var objectsDic: [Int : [[Object]]]
```

I finally found a way that works

```
objectsDic.map { $0.value }.flatMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0 }
```

Is there a better way to do this without using two separate flat map calls? Thanks!

Comment: Alternative: `Array(objectsDic.values.joined().joined())`

Comment: Well you can turn the first `map` into a `flatMap` and take out the last call... but that's still two `flatMap` calls.

Comment: @MartinR yeah `joined()` is a bit nicer than `flatMap { $0 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hybrid of some of the suggestions in the comments, and I believe the most concise notation:

```
objectsDict.flatMap{$0.value.joined()}
```